# Get full path of the files in PowerShell

Tags: powershell, powershell-2.0

I need to get all the files including the files present in the subfolders that belong to a particular type.

I am doing something like this, using [Get-ChildItem](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh849800.aspx):

```
Get-ChildItem "C:\windows\System32" -Recurse | where {$_.extension -eq ".txt"}
```

However, it's only returning me the files names and not the entire path.

Answer (score 308, accepted):

Add `| select FullName` to the end of your line above.  If you need to actually do something with that afterwards, you might have to pipe it into a foreach loop, like so:

```
get-childitem "C:\windows\System32" -recurse | where {$_.extension -eq ".txt"} | % {
     Write-Host $_.FullName
}
```

Comment: This command did not traverse into subfolders. I removed `where` and it traversed

Answer (score 149):

This should perform much faster than using late filtering:

```
Get-ChildItem C:\WINDOWS\System32 -Filter *.txt -Recurse | % { $_.FullName }
```

Comment: This is true. A caveat: this command actually gets files like `*.txt*` (`-Filter` uses CMD wildcards). If this is not what you want then use `-Include *.txt`.

Comment: `ls | % { $_.FullName }` to get full path in file listing ; assuming alias ls=Get-ChildItem

Answer (score 52):

You can also use [Select-Object](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh849895.aspx) like so:

```
Get-ChildItem "C:\WINDOWS\System32" *.txt -Recurse | Select-Object FullName
```

Comment: Note that `Select-Object` returns `PSCustomObject`, not a string. It might not work if you use result as parameter for another program

Comment: Yes to what @Chintsu said. To get strings instead of `PSCustomObject`, use `-ExpandProperty FullName` instead of simply `FullName`. As far as I understand, `-ExpandProperty` parameter causes the cmdlet to return the results as the specified property's (native?) type instead of as some custom object.

Comment: I needed time too (I'd messed with the source of a program and thought later that I should probably have started source control on it, but I can get an idea of my first commit against "master" by getting files since installation: `Get-ChildItem -Path 'C:\Program Files\TheProgram' -Recurse | Where-Object -FilterScript {($_.LastWriteTime -gt '2020-03-01')} | Select-Object FullName`

Answer (score 34):

Here's a shorter one:

```
(Get-ChildItem C:\MYDIRECTORY -Recurse).fullname > filename.txt
```

Comment: Here's a shorter one:
`(gci -r c:\).fullname`

Comment: Here's a shorter one: `(ls -r c:\).fullname`

Comment: Here's a shorter one: `(ls -r c:).fullname`

Answer (score 14):

If relative paths are what you want you can just use the `-Name` flag.

`Get-ChildItem "C:\windows\System32" -Recurse -Filter *.txt -Name`

Comment: This doesn't seem to give the relative path, only the filename. Could you provide an example?

Comment: If the file is in the folder you start in, it only shows the filename. If it is in a subfolder it will give `subfolder/file.txt`

Comment: -Name only gives the filename, not the path

Comment: No, it gives the relative path, as stated in my answer and in my previous comment. It's not exactly what the OP asked for, but can be a useful supplement.

Answer (score 8):

```
Get-ChildItem -Recurse *.txt | Format-Table FullName
```

That is what I used.  I feel it is more understandable as it doesn't contain any loop syntax.

Answer (score 8):

I used this line command to search ".xlm" files in "C:\Temp" and the result print fullname path in file "result.txt":

```
(Get-ChildItem "C:\Temp" -Recurse | where {$_.extension -eq ".xml"} ).fullname > result.txt
```

In my tests, this syntax works beautiful for me.

Comment: .FullName was what I needed!

Answer (score 7):

Really annoying thing in PS 5, where $_ won't be the full path within foreach.  These are the string versions of FileInfo and DirectoryInfo objects.  For some reason a wildcard in the path fixes it, or use Powershell 6 or 7.  You can also pipe to get-item in the middle.

```
Get-ChildItem -path C:\WINDOWS\System32\*.txt -Recurse | foreach { "$_" }

Get-ChildItem -path C:\WINDOWS\System32 -Recurse | get-item | foreach { "$_" }
```

This seems to have been an issue with .Net that got resolved in .Net Core (Powershell 7):  [Stringification behavior of FileInfo / Directory instances has changed since v6.0.2 #7132](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/issues/7132#issuecomment-501451500)

Answer (score 5):

This worked for me, and produces a list of names:

```
$Thisfile=(get-childitem -path 10* -include '*.JPG' -recurse).fullname
```

I found it by using `get-member -membertype properties`, an incredibly useful command. most of the options it gives you are appended with a `.<thing>`, like `fullname` is here. You can stick the same command;

```
  | get-member -membertype properties
```

at the end of any command to get more information on the things you can do with them and how to access those:

```
get-childitem -path 10* -include '*.JPG' -recurse | get-member -membertype properties
```

Answer (score 3):

```
gci "C:\WINDOWS\System32" -r -include .txt | select fullname
```

Comment: Could you please elaborate more your answer adding a little more description about the solution you provide?

Answer (score 3):

I am using below script to extact all folder path:

```
Get-ChildItem -path "C:\" -Recurse -Directory -Force -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue | Select-Object FullName | Out-File "Folder_List.csv"
```

Full folder path is not coming. After 113 characters, is coming:

```
Example - C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\Windows\DeviceMetadataCache\dmrccache\en-US\ec4d5fdd-aa12-400f-83e2-7b0ea6023eb7\Windows...
```

Answer (score 3):

Why has nobody used  the foreach loop yet? A pro here is that you can easily name your variable:

```
# Note that I'm pretty explicit here. This would work as well as the line after:
# Get-ChildItem -Recurse C:\windows\System32\*.txt
$fileList = Get-ChildItem -Recurse -Path C:\windows\System32 -Include *.txt
foreach ($textfile in $fileList) {
    # This includes the filename ;)
    $filePath = $textfile.fullname
    # You can replace the next line with whatever you want to.
    Write-Output $filePath
}
```

Comment: how can I get the individual filepath of a textfile without using foreach textfile in fileList? something like textfile= $fileList[$i].fullname, I know is not the most optimal approach but I need to make it this way :(

Comment: Just add a `$` in front of `textfile`: `$textfile = $fileList[$i].FullName`. Assuming `$i` has a numeric value, that is.

Answer (score 1):

[alternative syntax]

For some people, directional pipe operators are not their taste, but they rather prefer chaining. See some interesting opinions on this topic shared in roslyn issue tracker: [dotnet/roslyn#5445](https://github.com/dotnet/roslyn/issues/5445).

Based on the case and the context, one of this approach can be considered implicit (or indirect). For example, in this case using pipe against enumerable requires special token `$_` (aka `PowerShell's "THIS" token`) might appear distasteful to some.

For such fellas, here is a more concise, straight-forward way of doing it with *dot chaining*:

```
(gci . -re -fi *.txt).FullName
```

*(<rant> Note that PowerShell's command arguments parser accepts the partial parameter names. So in addition to `-recursive`; `-recursiv`, `-recursi`, `-recurs`, `-recur`, `-recu`, `-rec` and `-re` are accepted, but unfortunately not `-r` .. which is the only correct choice that makes sense with single `-` character (if we go by POSIXy UNIXy conventions)! </rant>)*

Comment: Note to the rant: the `-r` short form of `-Recurse` works fine for me.

Comment: @Polymorphix, you are right, it is working for me on Windows 10 (not sure which version I was trying earlier). However, same holds true with `-File` switch `-fi` in the sample: `-fil` and `-file` works, but not `-f`. Going by POSIX style, it should be `--file` (multi-letters) and `-f` (single-letter, unless -f is reserved for something else, say `force` switch, then it can be something else like `-l` or no single-letter option at all).

Answer (score 0):

I had an issue where I had an executable file which had directory path strings as parameters and the format. Like this:

"C:\temp\executable.exe" "C:\storage\filename" "C:\storage\dump" -jpg

I needed to execute this command across terabytes of .jpg files in different folders.

```
$files = Get-ChildItem  -Path C:\storage\*.jpg -Recurse -Force | Select-Object -ExpandProperty FullName

for ($i=0; $i -lt $files.Count; $i++) {
    [string]$outfile = $files[$i]
    
    Start-Process -NoNewWindow -FilePath "C:\temp\executable.exe" -ArgumentList $outfile, "C:\storage\dump", "-dcm"
   

}
```