# Debugging disk space cleanup script - Deleting files it should not be

Tags: arrays, powershell, logging

I am working on a disk space script for our clients in my off time. I just tested it using the ISE, and it looks like it was working until I checked the transcript.

There are sections during the first removal cycle around line 32 where it is removing files in C:\Windows\System32\, which of course I didn't want it to. I am sure I did something wrong, but I have checked for typos, and I do not understand how it can get %system32% from a users directory.

```cs
If (([Security.Principal.WindowsPrincipal][Security.Principal.WindowsIdentity]::GetCurrent()).IsInRole([System.Security.Principal.WindowsBuiltInRole]::Administrator))
    {
        $Host.UI.RawUI.WindowTitle = $myInvocation.MyCommand.Definition + ' (Elevated)'
        $Host.UI.RawUI.BackgroundColor = 'DarkBlue'
        Clear-Host
    }
Else
    {
        $newProcess = New-Object Diagnostics.ProcessStartInfo 'PowerShell'
        $newProcess.Arguments = "& '" + $script:MyInvocation.MyCommand.Path + "'"
        $newProcess.Verb = 'runas'
        [Diagnostics.Process]::Start($newProcess) | Out-Null
        exit
    }
If ((Test-Path "C:\DiskSpaceCleanupLog\") -eq $False)
    {
        New-Item -ItemType Directory -Path "C:\DiskSpaceCleanupLog\"
    }
$Date = [string]::Format( "{0:dd-MM-yyyy}", [datetime]::Now.Date )
$LogName = "C:\DiskSpaceCleanupLog\" + $Date + "Log.txt"
Start-Transcript $LogName
$Path = @()
$Array = @(Get-ChildItem C:\Users | Select-Object Name)
Read-Host -Verbose "Removing User Account temp files..."
Foreach ($Name IN $Array)
    {

        $Path = ("C:\Users\" + $Name.Name + "\AppData\Local\Temp\")
    }              
Foreach ($Path IN $Array)
    {
        Get-ChildItem | Remove-Item -Recurse -WhatIf
    }
Remove-Variable Path
Read-Host -Verbose "Removing User Account crash dumps..."
Foreach ($Name IN $Array)
    {
        $Path = ("C:\Users\" + $Name.Name + "\AppData\Local\CrashDumps\")
    }
Foreach ($Path IN $Array)
    {
        Get-ChildItem | Remove-Item -Recurse -WhatIf
    }
Remove-Variable Path
Read-Host -Verbose "Removing User Account reporting files..."
Foreach ($Name IN $Array)
    {
        $Path = ("C:\Users\" + $Name.Name + "\AppData\Local\Microsoft\Windows\WER\ReportArchive\")
    }              
Foreach ($Temp IN $Path)
    {
        Get-ChildItem | Remove-Item -Recurse -WhatIf
    }
Remove-Variable Path
Read-Host -Verbose "Removing User Account temp files from Internet Explorer..."
Foreach ($Name IN $Array)
    {
        $Path = ("C:\Users\" + $Name.Name + "\AppData\Local\Microsoft\Windows\Temporary Internet Files\")
    }              
Foreach ($Temp IN $Path)
    {
        Get-ChildItem | Remove-Item -Recurse -WhatIf
    }
Read-Host -Verbose "Removing Recycle Bin files..."
Remove-Item -LiteralPath 'C:\$Recycle.Bin\' -Recurse -WhatIf
Read-Host -Verbose "Removing global crash dumps..."
Remove-Item "C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\Windows\WER\ReportQueue" -Recurse -WhatIf
Remove-Item "C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\Windows\WER\ReportArchive" -Recurse -WhatIf
Read-Host -Verbose "Removing Windows Update cached files..."
Stop-Service -DisplayName 'Windows Update'
Remove-Item "C:\Windows\SoftwareDistribution\Download\*" -Recurse -WhatIf
Start-Service -DisplayName 'Windows Update'
Remove-Variable Array, Path
Read-Host -Verbose "Cleaning base image of update cache..."
DISM.exe /Online /Cleanup-Image /SPSuperseded
Read-Host -Verbose "Running Windows Clean Manager..."
$OSVersion = Get-WMIObject -Class Win32_OperatingSystem | Format-Table Version
If ($OSVersion -le 6.1)
    {
        cleanmgr.exe /verylowdisk
    }
Read-Host -Verbose "Removal is complete. Sending logs..."
Stop-Transcript
$SecurePassword = ConvertTo-SecureString "InsertPasswordHere" -AsPlainText -Force
$emailcredential = New-Object System.Management.Automation.PSCredential ("email@domain.com", $SecurePassword)
Send-MailMessage -To "Name Here <email@domain.com>" -From "Name Here <email@domain.com>" -Subject ("Disk Space Cleanup Log - " + $Date) -Body "Attached is the log from the script." -Attachments $LogName -SmtpServer "smtp.office365.com" -Credential $emailcredential -UseSSL -Port "587" -DeliveryNotificationOption OnFailure
```

Line 32 is `Get-ChildItem | Remove-Item -Recurse -WhatIf`

Comment: Perhaps a user has a shortcut to C:\Windows\System32 somewhere in their directory?

Comment: I am testing on my PC, and I don't have any links like that. Or junction points either.

I didnt think of that though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The are several things that should be adjusted in your code but the issue that is befalling you now is that you have not specified a `-Path`. Therefore `Get-ChildItem` will be returning items from the *working directory*!

```
 Get-ChildItem | Remove-Item -Recurse -WhatIf
```

Should be instead

```
 Get-ChildItem $path | Remove-Item -Recurse -WhatIf
```

Like I said though there are several potential pitfalls and areas of improvement there to be addressed. You use the same loop 5 times. A couple are exactly the same.

Comment: Doh! Well that's one. Can you see any others?

Using writing these as a learning experience.

Comment: @Moridn If you get the script working then I would suggest going to CodeReview.SE. StackOverlflow is more geared to specific problems and answers.

Answer (score 0):

I believe the issue is on line 23, where the code is not populating the array with full pathnames.  See [Get full path of the files in PowerShell](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13126175/get-full-path-of-the-files-in-powershell) for some advice on how to get the full pathnames instead.

Comment: I added the full name modifier to the path, and it is still attempting to delete files in the system32 directory.

 To clarify, #32 looks like this now. 

Get-ChildItem | % { $_.FullName } | Remove-Item -Recurse -WhatIf