# return array of objects from Get-ChildItem -Path

Tags: windows, powershell, file, directory, system-administration

From powershell, `ls -R *.txt` will list files recursively by directory, or, even better:

```
PS> Get-ChildItem -Path C:\Test -Name
```

logs

```
anotherfile.txt
Command.txt
CreateTestFile.ps1
ReadOnlyFile.txt
```

but how do I feed this into an array?  I would like an array of the file (?) object itself, looking at:

`Get-ChildItem "C:\WINDOWS\System32" *.txt -Recurse | Select-Object FullName`

https://stackoverflow.com/a/24468733/262852

I'm looking for an array of "file" objects with powershell from these types of commands.

probably better syntax:

`Copy-Item -Filter *.txt -Path c:\data -Recurse -Destination C:\temp\text`

but rather than copy the items, I just want an object, or rather, array of objects.  Not the path to a file, not the file, but, presumably, a powershell reference or pointer to a file.

(Reading the [fine](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/scripting/samples/working-with-files-and-folders?view=powershell-6#listing-all-the-files-and-folders-within-a-folder) manual now.)

Comment: `get-ChildItem "C:\windows\system32" -include "*.txt" -Recurse` produces an array of objects.

Comment: I am not sure what you are getting at here. But powershell automatically returns an object. All you have to do is assign it to a variable. `$txtfiles = Get-ChildItem "C:\WINDOWS\System32" *.txt -Recurse | Select-Object FullName`. In this case, `$txtfiles` will be an array object.

Comment: @AdminOfThings the array will contain objects of type `System.IO.FileSystemInfo`?  Okay, that was what I needed to know.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`Get-ChildItem "C:\test" -Recurse` will return an array of FileInfo and DirectoryInfo objects inside an array

We can see an a example showing that here

```
Get-ChildItem "C:\test" -Recurse | %{
    $_.gettype()
}
```

Returns

```
IsPublic IsSerial Name                                     BaseType
-------- -------- ----                                     --------
True     True     DirectoryInfo                            System.IO.FileSystemInfo
True     True     DirectoryInfo                            System.IO.FileSystemInfo
True     True     FileInfo                                 System.IO.FileSystemInfo
True     True     DirectoryInfo                            System.IO.FileSystemInfo
```

Comment: Exactly what I needed to know, thanks.  This is a standard idiom for getting the type?

Comment: this answer is misleading, because `Get-ChildItem -Recurse` sometimes does not return an array. see mklement0's answer.

Comment: @orionelenzil Misleading is a strong word. He asked for a answer and I gave him one. My answer works for what he wanted. He even replied below stating thanks but it was "over his head". Sometimes in-depth explanations are not always needed or wanted.

Comment: I dunno. if `c:\test` contains only a single file, the resulting type is `System.IO.FileSystemInfo`.

Comment: You may be right that 'misleading' is too strong a word. I'm picking this nit because this particular behavior has tripped me up several times - I write my script against a search that returns many files and all is well, `$x.Length` equals the number of items, etc, but then my script runs somewhere the search returns only a single item and now my code breaks. `$x.Length` is the filesize of the one file returned, etc.

Comment: @orionelenzil that is a legit concern. Fair enough

Answer (score 9):

**tl;dr**

- When you capture a PowerShell statement's output in a variable (e.g., 
  `$output = Get-ChildItem ...`), it is *automatically* collected in an array if there are *two or more* output objects.
- To ensure that an array is *always* used - even with only a *single* or *no* output object - use `@(...)` (e.g., 
  `$output = @(Get-ChildItem ...)`)

---

- PowerShell cmdlets, such as `Get-ChildItem`, can output any number of objects.

  - `Get-ChildItem` outputs `[System.IO.FileInfo]` and/or `[System.IO.DirectoryInfo]` objects, depending on whether information about files and/or directories is being output.
  - To **determine a given cmdlet's output-object types**:

    - Run, e.g., `(Get-Command Get-ChildItem).OutputType`
    - If that doesn't work, or to see what types are output for a specific invocation, use
      `Get-ChildItem | Get-Member`.
    - `Get-Help -Full Get-ChildItem` should show an `OUTPUTS` section as well, as does the [online help](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.management/get-childitem#outputs), though not that in the case of `Get-ChildItem` it is less specific, since `Get-ChildItem` also works with providers other than the filesystem.
- When **output to the *pipeline*, each output object is passed *individually* to the next command in the pipeline** for typically immediate processing.
- When **output is captured in a *variable* (`$var = ...`)**, the following logic applies:

  - If *two or more* objects are output, they are collected in a regular PowerShell array, which is of type `[object[]]` (even though the actual elements have specific types).
  - If *one* object is output, it is output *as-is*; that is, it is *not* wrapped in an array.
  - If *no* objects are output, an "array-valued null" is output (sometimes called "AutomationNull" for its type name), which in expression contexts behaves like `$null` and in enumeration contexts like an *empty collection*; it results in no visible output - see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41568525/45375) for details.

Therefore, **when captured in a variable, a given command may *situationally* return**:

- an array of objects
- a single object
- "nothing" (`[System.Management.Automation.Internal.AutomationNull]::Value`)

**To ensure that a given command's output is *always* treated as an *array***, you have two options:

- Use `@(...)`, the [array subexpression operator](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_operators#array-subexpression-operator--); e.g.

  - `$fileSystemObjects = @(Get-ChildItem -Recurse -Filter *.txt)`
- Type-constrain the target variable with `[array]` (which is equivalent to, and easier to type than, `[object[]]`).

  - `[array] $fileSystemObjects = Get-ChildItem -Recurse -Filter *.txt`

That said, **in PSv3+ you often need not worry about whether a given variable contains a scalar (single value) or an array**, because **scalars can implicitly be treated like arrays**: you can call `.Count` even on scalars, and use indexing (`[0]`, `[-1]`) - see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44035802/45375) for details.

Comment: okay, and thanks for the pointers about how to handle types and arrays.  I like the `Get-Member` commandlet.

Comment: @Thufir; my pleasure. The answer you accepted tells you what specific types `Get-ChildItem` returns, which may be what you _meant_ to ask, but it is not what you _did_ ask. Please consider the perspective of future readers.

Comment: TL;DR Use `@(...)` to ensure output is always treated as an array!