# How to ALWAYS return an array from Get-ChildItem and similar functions?

Tags: powershell

I have a PowerShell script which processes all files in a directory, but it breaks when there is **exactly 0 or 1** file in a directory, which I tracked down to `Get-ChildItem`'s unexpected behavior:

```
mkdir C:\Temp\demo1 ; cd C:\Temp\demo1
(gci).Length  # 0
# (gci).GetType().Name  # error: null-valued expression

ni 1.txt
(gci).Length  # 0 ???
(gci).GetType().Name  # FileInfo

ni 2.txt
(gci).Length  # 2
(gci).GetType().Name  # Object[]

ni 3.txt
(gci).Length  # 3
(gci).GetType().Name  # Object[]
```

- For 0 items, `gci` returns `$null`
- For 1 item, `gci` returns a `FileInfo` object
- For 2+ items, `gci` returns an `Object[]` as expected

How can I make `Get-ChildItem` always return an `Object[]`?

Comment: Be careful, you can also get a `DirectoryInfo` if the directory contains an other directory, and Object[] may be an array of non homogenous objects.  Behind the scene these CmdLets (ending with item) are a bit more complex than simple `dir` or `ls`. You can use them to work on registry, list of vars or certificates. Have a look to  Get-PSProvider and Get-PSDrive.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [return array of objects from Get-ChildItem -Path](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55765010/return-array-of-objects-from-get-childitem-path), see  also`about-arrays`: [The array sub-expression operator](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_arrays#the-array-sub-expression-operator)

Comment: @iRon The question title is matching, but the question content is totally different. IMO OP thought they were getting back a string instead of an object array, which is both not true and a separate issue.

Comment: @xjcl, (I have removed the duplicate vote) eventho, I think that the [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55767507/1701026) covers the title. Besides this is a [classic PowerShell gotcha (#4)](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69644807/1701026) related to the pipeline enrolling. Maybe it is indeed good to have (again?) a specific question about this but I would and more details in the answer, and have a more positive approach as some might call it *buggy* and others *magic*: You need an Object[]? Did you ask for it? The ETS will just do it for you: `[object[]](gci)`

Comment: @iRon I didn't include `[object[]](gci)` in the answer because it doesn't work if there are 0 files and `gci` returns the `$null` object

Comment: @iRon I meant that it lead to buggy behavior in my subsequent code, I wasn't calling PS buggy. I'll rephrase it

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Simply wrap the call inside of the **array operator** `@(...)` i.e. `@(gci)`:

```
mkdir C:\Temp\demo2 ; cd C:\Temp\demo2
@(gci).Length  # 0
@(gci).GetType().Name  # Object[]

ni 1.txt
@(gci).Length  # 1
@(gci).GetType().Name  # Object[]
```